# Need a WYSIWYG web editor for the RTF format

Tags: editor, wysiwyg, rtf

I need a WYSIWYG editor I can put on my website for editing [RTF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format) documents. It is important that the current RTF codes in the document are retained, and I'm forced to use the RTF format  due to the data being used in other applications requiring RTF. So any conversion back and forth would not be feasible.

I haven't been able to find one. Does it really not exist?

Comment: I don't know any browser based WYSIWYG editor which can edit RTF files and I know the market pretty well. You may try to find a good set of converters (RTF->HTML and HTML->RTF) and use regular WYSIWYG.

Comment: If Java is an option, there might be some solutions..  I remember looking into this a few years ago as well, and there was nothing but overpriced conversion libraries.